# Unsure on Riemann Sum to Definite Integral

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I've taught definite integrals for high school twice, but everytime I run into this particular Riemann Sum to Definite Integral question that I can't seem to solve.

The question is:

> If $n$ is a positive integer, then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{4}{n} \bigg[ \bigg(2+ \frac{4}{n}\bigg)+ \bigg(2+ \frac{5}{n}\bigg) + \bigg(2+ \frac{6}{n}\bigg) + \ldots \bigg(2+ \frac{n}{n}\bigg) \bigg]$ can be expressed as what definite integral?

I have attempted a solution by letting $\Delta x= \frac{4}{n}=(b-a)/n$ and based on the function inside, it seems like $f(x)=x$.  Trying to find the bounds of integration is where my solution is dependent on my assumption since I usually assume $a=2$ based on how the sum is written.  This does not seem right.

After attempting it once again, I ended up with something like  $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n  \bigg[ \bigg(2+ \frac{k(1+\frac{3}{k})}{n}\bigg) \bigg] \frac{4}{n}$
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^{1}4(2+x)dx=\lim \frac  1 n \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} 4(2+\frac i n)$. This is same as the given limit since the limit of $\frac  1 n  4(2+\frac i n)$ is $0$ for $i\leq 3$. So the answer is $10$.

Comment: I had written an answer with almost same idea. I have deleted it now. +1 already for you.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you.